# GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Window system doesn't support OpenGL

Tags: opencv, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, raspbian, imshow

I am using Opencv in raspberry pi 2. It was working fine but after upgrading it to raspbian Jessie it is showing following error when cv::imshow() function is called:
`GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Window system doesn't support OpenGL` 
and crashes.
Tried installing libgl1-mesa-dri but it is already the latest version. Can anyone tell what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by replacing tightvncserver with vnc4server along with other packages as shown in the bash script below:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Make sure only root can run our script
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
dpkg --purge tightvncserver
dpkg -i xbitmaps_1.1.1-2_all.deb
dpkg -i x11-apps_7.7+4_armhf.deb
dpkg -i x11-session-utils_7.7+1_armhf.deb
dpkg -i xbase-clients_1%3a7.7+7_all.deb
dpkg -i vnc4server_4.1.1+X4.3.0-37.6_armhf.deb
# Restart vnc running script in background
systemctl restart vncboot.service
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Where is this bash script?

Comment: Script is mentioned in answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38396933/1858124). I didn't have access to internet on pi (at remote location) so wrote this script.. you can download these packages mentioned in script and install vnc4server